# javascript:history.go does not refresh page on mobile phone?

Tags: javascript

The below Href tag does not refresh the page from a mobile phone `javascript:history.go(0)` but works when tried on my laptop ? Is there a diffrent way to refresh page if using on a mobile phone ?

Note i am using HTML5 CSS an Javascript to build a mobile app here.

```
<a HREF="javascript:history.go(0)" class="ui-btn ui-btn-b" data-role="button" >Reset </a>
```

Comment: I think 0 would stay on same page please write `(-1)` for previous page or write `location.reload()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
location.reload();
```

[Location reload() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_reload.asp)

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
window.top.location.reload();
```